# Trying to import GoogleMobileAds causes compilation (link) error

Tags: ios, import, frameworks, admob

I downloaded the latest GoogleMobileAds SDK, put it in the directory  where my other Frameworks are located, and then imported the framework (Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries)

But even without referring this SDK it in the code, the compilation fails:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKView", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-arm64)
> ```
>
> "_GLKMatrix4Identity", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   l13228 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-arm64)
>
>   l13240 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-arm64)
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Any help or hint you provide is much appreciated